# How to skip SWIG directives in clang-format

Tags: swig, clang-format

We use SWIG to generate Python wrappers for some C++ code. SWIG directives start with %, and look like this in headers:

```
#ifdef SWIG
%apply int* INT_RET_VAL{int * is_donor};
#ENDIF
ErrLevel mmct_hbond_is_donor(MM_Index ct, int atom_idx, int* is_donor);
#ifdef SWIG
%clear int * is_donor;
#ENDIF
```

When clang-format processes them, the `%apply` turns to `% apply`, which is not a SWIG statement anymore! There are *lots* of these in our code base currently. Is there a good way to convince clang-format to skip the %apply and %clear statements? Or maybe everything in an `#ifdef SWIG`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `// clang-format off`.

```
int formatted_code;
// clang-format off
    void    unformatted_code  ;
// clang-format on
void formatted_code_again;
```

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#disabling-formatting-on-a-piece-of-code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't think this will work for us, though. If you apply this suggestion to my original question, 4 more lines will be added to the header, further obscuring the (fairly simple) function declaration.

Comment: If that is unacceptable, then you can consider not using this `#ifdef SWIG` approach and extract swig directives to external .i file. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.